# Chessboard tree diagram

Tags: diagrams, trees, chess, chessboard

I'm wanting to draw a chessboard tree diagram and I am trying to find the best way to create the tree diagram part. So far I have the below but it looks like the chessboard has a white border which is cutting off the branches. This isn't a problem for the under part of the chessboards as there is text there anyway, but would ideally like the branches to finish just before the chessboard.

Is there something I can do using `\tikz` to get the branches to meet just before the chessboard?
If not `\tikz` then what suitable packages would create the same effect?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{3x3}{maxfield=c3}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\centering


\begin{tikzpicture}[
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=5.5cm,},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
        level distance=5cm,
        line width=2,]
\node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=b,addblack={pa3,pb3,pc2},addwhite={pa2,pb2,pc1},showmover=true,]}
    child {  node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=w,addblack={pb2,pb3,pc2},addwhite={pa2,pc1},showmover=true,]}
        child {  node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=w,addblack={pa3,pa2,pc2},addwhite={pb2,pc1},showmover=true,]}}
        child {  node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=w,addblack={pa3,pa2,pc2},addwhite={pb2,pc1},showmover=true,]}
            child {  node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=w,addblack={pa3,pa2,pc2},addwhite={pb2,pc1},showmover=true,]}}}}
    child {  node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=w,addblack={pa3,pa2,pc2},addwhite={pb2,pc1},showmover=true,]}
        child {  node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=w,addblack={pa3,pa2,pc2},addwhite={pb2,pc1},showmover=true,]}
            child {  node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=w,addblack={pa3,pa2,pc2},addwhite={pb2,pc1},showmover=true,]}
                child {  node {\chessboard[style=3x3,mover=w,addblack={pa3,pa2,pc2},addwhite={pb2,pc1},showmover=true,]}}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can change the margins and the padding, see the documentation.

Comment: Also, every node adds a margin of its own, so set [inner sep=0pt] (possibly [every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]).